# SWIG and Javascript: does embedding the JVM/Rhino into my C++ app is still the only solution?

Tags: javascript, swig, jvm-languages

I really like the idea of automatic binding generation like SWIG does. But it is still lacking Javascript binding. I read that it could not be done with Spidermonkey because of the JS Context that must be passed as parameter to each function.

The only solution I found is to embed a JVM into my C++ application, generating bindings to Java using SWIG, and then using Rhino engine as the JS interpreter. It works fine, but it is really heavyweight!

Any other ideas?

Note: yes I know, I could use Python or Lua instead. But my question is really about JS.

Comment: There is still no automatic binding generation software which target V8. And V8 is not Win64 friendly for now.. I need that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since I don't have any answers, I think that I must use other alternatives than SWIG.

I found [that page](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/SpiderMonkey/FOSS) on the mozilla developer center mentioning several projects for wrapping JS with the Spidermonkey engine: Spiderape, Flusspferd, TriXUL and jsapigen.

For V8, there is a similar project called v8-juice from the creator of Spiderape.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not in a hurry: Wait for the SWIG Javascript bindings that might be developed as GSoC-2012 project "New module for Javascript" by Neha Narang.

The [abstract](http://www.google-melange.com/gsoc/project/google/gsoc2012/narangneha03/13001) says:

> This project aims to add Javascript as a new supported target language
>   to swig to automate the generation of Javascript wrappers over C++.

The project repository is https://github.com/Neha03/gsoc2012-javascript.